# How to handle GZip/Deflate on HTTP Actions

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have [an HTTP Action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-http) in Azure Logic Apps that calls [a StackExchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/info?site=devops), fundamentally, it could be any API that returned [GZip or Deflate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression) content by default:

[image: Azure Logic Apps: HTTP Action]

Because the response is neither [Plain Text nor JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-content-type) the output from the HTTP Action is:

```
{
  "$content-encoding": "gzip",
  "$content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  "$content": "H4sIAAAAAAAEAGWPzY7CMAyE38XnqsrPFtq+ClpFoXghEkm6iVtWQrw7Lt3mAEd/Hs+M7+AIfYb+cIeAN2MHcjOaKWNiKCqgSPa6zZ2SFRzt6YzZjJiMd2EiZF0tvjbpuoZe7rrdxuZIC9KNLo5D9B4DLUIl2gpsyDfOeLflvN8JM7kYPnbF6/+WA/ZNYcOAI+Hp5V/eCKv0heVGSwD0SnRcZXQm4ewyM+hBCbmvda3aWjVaS3h8V3Cx2fiYuMePvWZcSrKV8faPSyzF1jmhty64cGbnVjyeRIHcnG0BAAA="
}
```

If you went to the trouble of passing the `$content` field through `@base64toString()` you would end up with the Gzip binary representation of the JSON, and that is as far as I can take it.

**Question**: How can I either force the HTTP Action to behave like a `HttpClient` and Accept GZip data and emit the JSON from the Action, or more laboriously take the GZip Base64/Binary data and decompress it before acting further upon it?

Comment: I was going to suggest adding a header ``accept-encoding:identity`` to disable gzip encoding but it looks like the API isn't respecting that.

Comment: I did try that, theoretically the HTTP action should take responsibility for negotiating the content, it seems to use HttpClient without configuring automated decompression.

Comment: I created a feature on our backlog to do this automatically, in the meanwhile, looks like you were able to workaround it via Functions.

Comment: Has anyone figured this out without having to enlist an Az Function to decompress the payload?  We are trying to accept a gzip webhook into a logic app and it's ugly to have to stand up a function shim to decompress and decode the payload.  APIM didn't help either, it just got confused I think as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to find a way to "solve" the problem directly, so I created an [Azure Function](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/functions/) that made the request to the URL with the appropriate [`HttpClientHandler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclienthandler(v=vs.118).aspx) passed into the [`HttpClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx):

```cs
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"

using System;
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public static async Task<object> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log) {
  string jsonContent = await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
  dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonContent);

  if (data.url == null) {
    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, new {
      error = "Please pass a URL in the input object"
    });
  }

  HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler() {
    AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate
  };

  var client = new HttpClient(handler);
  var result = await client.GetAsync((string)data.url);
  var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
  response.Content = result.Content;
  return response;
}
```

By swapping the built-in HTTP Action from the original question, I was able to get this working:

[image: Working Flow]

And the configuration for the Azure Function is as follows:

[image: Custom HTTP Action]